# How to stop a particular job while running Hive queries on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive

### Scenario:

```
When I run enter the query on Hive CLI, I get the errors as below:
```

### Query:

```
**$ bin/hive -e "insert overwrite table pokes select a.* from invites a where a.ds='2008-08-15';"**
```

### Error is like this:

> Total MapReduce jobs = 1
>       Launching Job 1 out of 1
>       Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
>       Starting Job = job_201111291547_0013, Tracking URL = http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201111291547_0013
>       Kill Command = C:\cygwin\home\Bhavesh.Shah\hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop job 
>   -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:9101 -kill job_201111291547_0013
>       2011-12-01 14:00:52,380 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
>       2011-12-01 14:01:19,518 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
>       Ended Job = job_201111291547_0013 with errors
>       FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

### Question:

So my question is that how to stop a job? In this case the job is : job_201111291547_0013 
Pls help me out so that I can remove these errors and try for next.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can stop a job by running `hadoop job -kill <job_id>`.

Answer (score 3):

`hadoop job -kill` is deprecated now. 
Use `mapred job -kill` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The log traces of the job launched provide the command to kill the job as well.You can use that to kill the job. 
That however gives a warning that `hadoop job -kill` is deprecated. You can also use instead

```
mapred job -kill
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to try WebHCat API from browser or command line, using utilities like Curl. Here's WebHCat [API to delete a hive job](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+DeleteJobID)

Also note that the link says that

> The job is not immediately deleted, therefore the information returned may not reflect deletion, as in our example. Use GET jobs/:jobid to monitor the job and confirm that it is eventually deleted.